# How to handle upvotes and downvotes of disqus comments after importing disqus comments to wordpress?

Tags: comments, disqus

I wanted to migrate disqus comments to my WordPress. I found some guide post

https://www.ampercent.com/migrate-disqus-comments-back-wordpress/21729/

https://help.disqus.com/import-export-and-syncing/importing-exporting

but I wanted know how will disqus comment votes work in the wordpress comments or it will not work.

Thanks

Comment: WordPress comments do not have voting. If you wanted voting on your comments you would need to find a plugin that does that. Then whether or not the Disqus votes will transfer will depend on the plugin.

Comment: Yes, I checked some voting plugins, they work with their own voting data. None of them is working with disqus voting data. :(

Comment: You should consider asking on Disqus forums. They already have a plugin for WordPress integration, they might offer migration too.